# loop over a list in a certain pattern

Tags: python

I want to iterate over a list that looks like 
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
my iteration pattern should looks like this:

```
outer loop/ inner loop
1,        / 2, 3,4,5,6
2,        /3, 4, 5, 6
3,        /4, 5, 6
4,        /5, 6
5,        /6
```

pseudocode

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
list2 = list1.copy()
list2=list2[-1:]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
       print i
       print j
    list2=list2[-1:]
```

I know how to do this in loops but is there a pythonic way to perform it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most efficient way (both in performance and in time spent programming) to get the values you want is by using `itertools.combinations` from the Python standard library to produce the pairs of values with a single loop:

```
 for i, j in itertools.combinations(list1, 2):
     print(i, j)
```

There's no need for any manual slicing or messing around with indexes. And it's probably faster than nested loops, since `itertools.combinations` is written in C.

Comment: It is twice slower than nested loops (1.2s instead of 0,66s on a list with 10000 items).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to copy the list.
And calling it `list` is a bad idea.

This will do what you want (nearly apart from whitespace in the output):

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for i in range(0, len(l)-1):
    print l[i],', /',','.join(map(str, l[i+1:]))
```

Comment: I don't want to print them. I want to loop over my list. the loop index will have this pattern described: (1,1),(1,2),...,(2,3),(2,4),...(3,4)...

Comment: You could add them to a new list then instead of printing.

Answer (score 1):

The idea to use two loops was good, but `list2[-1:]` only keeps the last element. To fix that, you would have to do this: `list2 = list2[1:]` or `list2.pop()`.

But these are inefficient, because they create a new copy of the list at each iteration of the outer loop. I suggest just manipulating the indices:

```
list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in list1[i:]:
       print list1[i]
       print j
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted doesn't achieve what you are aiming for. Rather, use something like this:

```
In [3]: my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

In [4]: for i,e1 in enumerate(my_list[:-1]):
   ...:     for e2 in my_list[i+1:]:
   ...:         print(e1,e2)
   ...:         
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
2 3
2 4
2 5
2 6
3 4
3 5
3 6
4 5
4 6
5 6
```

And if you are worried about making copies, use `islice` from `itertools`

```
In [16]: from itertools import islice

In [17]: stop = len(my_list)

In [18]: for i, e1 in enumerate(islice(my_list, stop)):
   ....:     for e2 in islice(my_list, i + 1, stop):
   ....:         print(e1,e2)
   ....:         
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
2 3
2 4
2 5
2 6
3 4
3 5
3 6
4 5
4 6
5 6
```

Although, at this point you may want to just work with indices and ranges like Valentin Lorentz suggests.